# How to implement a lock on a stream of data. Given a relational DB.?

Tags: database, stream, locking

Given a stream of data like set of id's which might be repetitive on a stream.
How to implement a lock on such stream such that only one id is processed at once.

Comment: Might be too broad. At least can you tell which tool you use?

Comment: Currently I consume messages from SQS queue. This queue has multiple consumers. Until the message is processed I can wait.